# Fill an ng2-select2 directive using Rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jquery-select2

I'm using Rxjs in order to get my billing plans. I want to set them in a select input.

Currently, I'm using [ng2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) in order to show these plans.

First of all, I need to get plans form server:

```
this.serverService
        .list()
        .subscribe(
            (result: any) => {
                for (let plan of result)
                    this.plans.push({id: plan.id, text: plan.name});
            },
            (error: any) => {

            }
        );
```

, where `this.plans` is an `Array<Select2OptionData>` field of my angular2 component.

So, `select2` is binded to `this.plans`:

```
<select2 id="default-select"
    (valueChanged)="select2Changed($event)"
    [data]="plans"   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    [width]="250"
    [theme]="'bootstrap'">
</select2>
```

Nevertheless, I don't quite understand WHEN and HOW to initialize `this.plans` field.

1. WHEN: on `constructor`? on `ngOnInit`, on a another function?
2. HOW: I'm using Rx, so when the subscription is well reached select2 directive values should show plans.

I hope I've explained so well.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your variable right when you define it:

```
private data: Array<Select2OptionData> = [];
```

This way you will have no problems waiting for your service to return the data.

Something I noticed is that your subscription to your service might result in duplicate entries in your data array, assuming that the observable always emits the complete list of options. However, I don't know if this is the case in your implementation.